# Command ls - A $path doesn't see desktop directory as empty. How come?

Tags: bash, if-statement, command, desktop, ls

```bash
if [ "$(ls -A $path)" ];then
echo $path
dirpath = "$mainPath/$path"
fi
```

Comment: Have you tried to print the result that you are testing on? `echo "$(ls -A $path)"` - it's not an empty string, is it?

Comment: Unrelated: `dirpath = "$mainPath/$path"` should be `dirpath="$mainPath/$path"`

Comment: Please add a suitable shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) and then paste your script at http://www.shellcheck.net/ and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: I have a broader code that uses the given condition. My problem wich is that command "ls -A $path" does see the Desktop directory as not empty. However, after putting the condition into a for loop that checks for every existing file and echoes it. The condition given above would make it so that only filled dictionaries and their paths to files would be printed out. Now I figured that desktop may contain hidden files and so passes the condition. My goal was to list all the files found in the main and sub directories. Not detecting and being able to read the hidden files makes it impossible.

Comment: copy/paste your code into https://shellcheck.net and fix any flagged issues. Be sure to include some sort of "shebang" first line, like `#!/bin/bash`. Good luck.

Comment: Also, having read your comment above (which should be in the body of your question, and clearly illustrated with examples), read about the *nix `find` command. It doesn't care about hidden files. `find "$path"` may be all  you need. Be sure to use it like `find ...  | while read -r file ; do echo "$file" ; done`` is a place to start (as the most basic example). Good luck.

Comment: Once you clear up the errors flagged by shellcheck, edit your Q to show your best attempt to solve your problem. Include a small set of sample file/dir names, the expected output, the current output and any error messages. Good luck.

Comment: Final comment : (-; ! ... `ls -A` is designed to show hidden files, that is files with `.` as the first char. It's not clear from your comment if you want to "find" hidden files or if you want to skip them. If you want to skip them, remove the `-A`. Generally using `ls` (with what ever options), is considered a shell anti-pattern. Use `find`. but if you must, then carefully read the man page for `ls` (with `man ls`) to understand what options are available to you. If you must use `ls` then check out the `-1` option, this is the best you can do for shell script processing. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the constructiveness of your critique.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the output of `ls` directly.

Instead:

```
if [ "$(ls -A "$path" | wc -l)" -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "$path"
    dirpath="$mainPath/$path"
fi
```

The program does this:

1. Listing files (`ls -A`)
2. Number of files (`wc -l`)
3. Is number of files not zero (`if`)

Hope it will help :)